# Python/pandas/numpy: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'capitalize'

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

An unusual question, in my remote docker environment linux gcc with `python` 2.7.6

```
sentence_case = {
  'value': np.asscalar(working_df.subject.isin(working_df.subject.str.capitalize()).sum()),
  'label': 'Sentence case'
}
```

correctly works and produces my array I am looking for, however in my local python anaconda distribution of the same version of 2.7.6, I get  `'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'capitalize'`

From what I've read on https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods this capitalize string method is "locale-dependent" which I'm not quite sure what that means but I can only conclude this is the reason for the error.

How should I go about error handling this or is there anything I can do to completely replicate the docker environment. Thanks for any help.

Comment: There were some changes made to the `string` methods API in `0.16.1` - perhaps a `pandas`, not `python` version conflict? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#string-methods-enhancements

Comment: definitely possible, but the pandas version in both instances are the same

Comment: thank you Stefan, my pandas was 0.15, updating solved this for me!

Comment: You're welcome - moved comment to answer the issue can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message suggests that the result of the `str` `StringMethod` as applied to a `pandas` `Series` does not have the attribute capitalize - so I would be looking for issues with the pandas version rather than with the `python` `string` methods.

The [locale](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) dependency refers to location-specific application of these methods, not the availability of methods per se.